# How we can get extension attribute of product in GraphQL Magento 2

Tags: magento2, graphql, pwa, extension-attributes

I want Stock_id in graphql. We can get this via [REST API](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/) but I need this in graphql.

Can anyone help me with this?

Please refer to the attached link and screenshot here [image]

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This following guide will help you to get "extension attribute of product in GraphQL Magento 2"

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-extension-attributes-to-entity-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the extension attributes in the query, the good way is to change the schema description and extend it in your own module.

Create **schema.graphqls** file in our custom modules (Vendor/CustomGQL) etc directory. Vendor_CustomGQL/etc/schema.graphqls

In schema.graphqls file, write your code to extend the functionality as:

```
interface ProductInterface {
attribute_set_id: Int
    @doc(description: "ID of the attribute set assigned to the product")
attribute_set_name: String
    @doc(description: "Name of attribute set assigned to the product")
    @resolver(class: "\\ExampleCorp\\CustomGQL\\Model\\Resolver\\ProductAttributeSetNameResolver") }
```

example

```
interface ProductInterface{
stock_id: String
    @doc(description: "Name of attribute set assigned to the product")
    @resolver(class: "\\CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\ProductStockSetNameResolver"), }
```

The attribute_set_id field is already present in the original schema, so the field described in our new schema will override the field present in the ProductInterface object.

The attribute_set_name field is not present in the orignal schema, so the field is added to the ProductInterface object by extending it.

**Resolver file**

For setting value create the resolver in your module:
Vendor_CustomGQL/Model/Resolver/ProductStockSetNameResolver.php

write your code to return the value of the custom extension attribute:

```
<?php

namespace ExampleCorp\CustomGQL\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

/**
 * Class to resolve custom attribute_set_name field in product GraphQL query
 */
class ProductAttributeSetNameResolver implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeSetRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $setRepository;

    public function __construct(AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $setRepository)
    {
        $this->setRepository = $setRepository;
    }

    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        return $this->setRepository->get($value['attribute_set_id'])->getAttributeSetName();
    }
}
```

For full documentation please check this: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/develop/extend-existing-schema/